# amp-carousel-button COLOR

Tags: wordpress, amp-html

I'm trying to change the background color of the arrows in .amp-carousel-button.

We talking about "WORDPRESS"

In both the custom css and adding the custom code in the "HEAD", the background color does not change, but the basic color remains.
I'm probably doing something wrong.

In the custum css I added:
both in this way:

```
/ * Color Carousel Arrows * /
div.amp-carousel-button-prev {
background-color: rgba (150,30,30,0.5);
}
/ * Color Carousel Arrows * /
div.amp-carousel-button-next {
background-color: rgba (150,30,30,0.5);
}
```

that in this other way:

```
/ * Color Carousel Arrows * /
.amp-carousel-button-prev {
background-color: rgba (150,30,30,0.5);
}
/ * Color Carousel Arrows * /
.amp-carousel-button-next {
background-color: rgba (150,30,30,0.5);
}
```

but that doesn't work

So I tried to put this code in the Head of the site:

```
<style amp-custom>
div.amp-carousel-button {
background-color: rgba (150,30,30,0.5);
}
</ Style>
```

as I also entered

```
<style amp-custom>
.amp-carousel-button {
background-color: rgba (150,30,30,0.5);
}
</ Style>
```

Anything! the background color always remains the default

Answer (score 0):

I tried in the amp-playground, and it did work!

[image: I tried in the amp-playground, and it did work!]